# Android App returning Null from API

Tags: c#, android, json, rest

Building an Android App to incorporate web services from a RESTful API in C#. I want to able to retrieve just some raw JSON at this stage to ensure the connection is working. The local host URL for the API is showing the data as below:

[image: The JSON at the local host address]

The URL string in the Android application is set to the external IP address but the app just shows null when I call for the data on the app.

Android App code - Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

private static final String JSON_URL =
        "http://**.***.***.***:5495/api/StudentAPI/GetAllStudent";

private boolean networkOk;
TextView output;

private BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String message =
                intent.getStringExtra(myService.MY_SERVICE_PAYLOAD);
        output.append(message + "\n");
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);

    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext())
            .registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver,
                    new IntentFilter(myService.MY_SERVICE_MESSAGE));

    networkOk = NetworkHelper.hasNetworkAccess(this);
    output.append("Network ok: " + networkOk);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext())
            .unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver);
}

public void  runClickHandler(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, myService.class);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse(JSON_URL));
    startService(intent);
}

public void clearClickHandler(View view){output.setText(""); }


}
```

My Service:

```
public class myService extends IntentService {

public static final String TAG = "MyService";
public static final String MY_SERVICE_MESSAGE = "myServiceMessage";
public static final String MY_SERVICE_PAYLOAD = "myServicePayload";

public myService() {
    super("MyService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Uri uri = intent.getData();
    Log.i(TAG, "onHandleIntent: " + uri.toString());

    String response;

    try {
        response =
                HttpHelper.downloadUrl(uri.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

    Intent messageIntent = new Intent(MY_SERVICE_MESSAGE);
    messageIntent.putExtra(MY_SERVICE_PAYLOAD, response);
    LocalBroadcastManager manager =
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
    manager.sendBroadcast(messageIntent);

}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.i(TAG, "onCreate");
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.i(TAG, "onDestroy");
}
}
```

Network Helper:

```
public class NetworkHelper {

public static boolean hasNetworkAccess(Context context){

    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)
            context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    try {
        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetwork != null &&
                activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

Http Helper Class:

```
public class HttpHelper {

/**
 * Returns text from a URL on a web server
 *
 * @param address
 * @return
 * @throws IOException
 */
public static String downloadUrl(String address) throws IOException {

    InputStream is = null;
    try {

        URL url = new URL(address);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.connect();

        int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
        if (responseCode != 200) {
            throw new IOException("Got response code " + responseCode);
        }
        is = conn.getInputStream();
        return readStream(is);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (is != null) {
            is.close();
        }
    }
    return null;
}

/**
 * Reads an InputStream and converts it to a String.
 *
 * @param stream
 * @return
 * @throws IOException
 */
private static String readStream(InputStream stream) throws IOException {

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArray = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    BufferedOutputStream out = null;
    try {
        int length = 0;
        out = new BufferedOutputStream(byteArray);
        while ((length = stream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        out.flush();
        return byteArray.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } finally {
        if (out != null) {
            out.close();
        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: was it working on localhost?

Comment: No. As i'm testing on a physical device I assumed you would need the external IP address.

Comment: Set a breakpoint and figure out what's going wrong.  Are you getting a 200?  Something else?  Throwing an exception?  You need to do the background research first, nobody's going to build this much code to debug it for you.

Comment: what's the responseCode, it shows in the downloadUrl() ?

Comment: Taking @GabeSechen advice I've ran in debug mode and it's showing that the connection there seem to be one error.

java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /**.***.***.*** (port 5495) after 15000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)

Is this potentially a problem with the port the API is using?

Comment: run webapi, try with http://**.***.***.***:5495/api/StudentAPI/GetAllStudent i.e. with IP that u r using on android on browser or fiddler, if it doesnt than you should work on getting that fixed

Answer (score 0):

First, figure out if the problem is in the service or in your app. 
 
Make the HTTP request from [here](http://wst.mytechlabs.com/) with all given parameters, if it works, then your service is OK. 
 
Now, follow these steps to figure out the problem on local side.

Run a debug on `downloadUrl()` and check the value of `responseCode` if its 200, then the request is good, now just clean and rebuild your project.

If its not 200, then follow these:

1. `extends` the HttpHelper class from `AsyncTask`
2. Now move your code to `doInBackground()` from `downloadUrl()`
3. Now debug this class for responseCode.

Comment: I have taken the above steps and found the following:  

The service is fine and returns the raw json  

I have ensured the port is accepting connections within the firewall settings  

I re-formatted the code as you said and when using the public ip address (31.185.x.x) the connection is refused. When using the private address (192.168.x.x) it responds with a 400 responseCode.

Comment: Use private ip address for this but before that, allow external requests from your server/dbms etc.. in case of MySQL I had to allow it on apache.